# Is there a JavaDoc annotation that defines a function argument as a callback?

Tags: javascript, javadoc, phpstorm

Is there a javadoc way to tell PHPStorm that a Javascript function accepts a callback as a parameter?

```
/**
 * Calculates the and calls the callback function.
 *
 * @param {string} arg1 The argument.
 * @param {????} callback A function to be called.
 **/
foo: function(arg1,callback)
{
   //...
   callback();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use {function} type for this, like

```
/** 
 * @param {function(number):string} f 
 * @param {number} n 
 * @return {string} 
*/
function foo( f, n ){  return f(n); }
```

See [Google Closure compiler docs](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler), 'Type Expressions' section for more info

JSDoc 3 also introduces a @callback tag (http://usejsdoc.org/tags-callback.html), but it's not yet supported (see [this issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-8139))